# NestJS Creating tables automatically without applying migrations if project is started in dev mode

Tags: database, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

So I have a project which uses NestJS + TypeORM .

When i start the project in dev mode using `yarn start:dev`  before running any migration(DB is created at this point of time, but doesn't haveany tables), It creates all the tables automatically in DB apart from ***migrations*** table.

After that, if we try to run migration, it throws an error saying that table already exists which seems genuine.

So, why NestJS is automatically creating tables on `yarn start:dev` ?

Not sure how using `yarn start:dev` can create tables automatically.

Both Synchronize and migrationsRun is false.
AutoLoadentites is set to true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey try to setup `synchronize` as `false`.
`.env` get parsed as string by default. Even though `this.configService.get<boolean>` is used.

For ex.

```
 createTypeOrmOptions(): TypeOrmModuleOptions {
        return {
            ...
            synchronize: this.configService.get<string>('TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE') === 'true' ? true : false,
            ...
        };
    }
```

Comment: Why not just `this.configService.get<string>('TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE') === 'true'`

Comment: That can also be done.